# how to make texts in variable clickable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have it now that my text are rotating, I want it such that when you hover and click one word(eg. chocolate, sugar or cocoa", it gives a sentence, click another word, another sentence. and then the rotating words continue rotating.

Any ideas? Any help is deeply appreciated. Thanks, guys:)

JS:

```
var words = [
    '<span id="pasta">Penne</span>', 
    '<span id="meat">Italian Sausage</span>',
    '<span id="oil">Olive Oil</span>', 
    '<span id="onion">Onion</span>'];
var index = 0;


    $(document).ready(function rotate() {
      document.getElementById('text').innerHTML =words[(index++)%(words.length)];
      if($("#text").is(":hover")){
        setTimeout(rotate, 500);
      }
      else{
        setTimeout(rotate, 100);
      }
    })()


    $(function(){
        $('#pasta').on('click', function () {
            $("<li>Cook 8 ounces of pasta, according to its package directions.</li>").appendTo('#steps');

            $("#steps").html('<div id="text"></div>'); 
        }); 

    });
```

HTML:

```
 <div id="steps"> 

       <div id="text">

       </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: If your code has already been resolved, could you please post your solution as an answer in case it helps others?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say have the text in an anchor tag with `href="#"` and write a function that responds to the anchor's onclick. And change the text in that function and add the anchor tag ...

additionally style your anchor to look like plain text.

Comment: hi. i dont think i'm able to do that. because each text links to a different sentence. I'm using <span> for now. I just can't figure out the appendTo.

Comment: what cant you figure out about appendTo ?